# How to access remote desktop (like SSH -X) in a windows system?

Tags: windows, ssh, desktop, x-server

I've been struggling all around the interwebz and I couldn't find any useful answer.
I have a computer with a Windows OS that has some software that I just can't run on GNU/Linux.
But in GNU/Linux, to share remote windows, we just type in ssh -X and the magic of seamless windows happens.

I would love to do the same for a Windows OS, but ssh -X for a Windows machine would never work since Windows doesn't use X Server. So I've tried to use Xming and MobaXterm free to have a X running on Windows. But I couldn't find a way to make ssh -X to it correctly.

So, my goal is: access a Windows machine remotely, in a seamless fashion, having to see just the applications' windows I want, like we do when we run ssh -X for any GNU/Linux OS running X Server. We have teamviewer that sorta does that, but badly...

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this with a Windows server, then I believe you can expose RDP (remote desktop) over https. I believe you want to use RD gateway to set this up. Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you explain how to do this?